# Is there a way to find out the name of the method that resulted in a call to another method in ruby?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm just getting started with meta-programming, and am wondering if there's a way to view method chains similar to class ancestral chains?

For example, imagine I have a method that looks like this:

```
def method_a
  method_b
end

method_b    
  # ..    
end
```

If I call method_a like so:

```
method_a
```

It should run method_b

Is there a way **from within** method_b to determine that method_a was responsible for calling it?

Comment: This code is broken; the `def` inside `method_a` will add `method_b` to the *global namespace* (or class, if it's in one), then call it. After you call `method_a` from outside, you could call `method_b` directly.

Comment: Does `method_b` have to be defined as an inner method? Note that `method_a` will actually return whatever it was that `method_b` returns, not `method_b` directly...

Comment: My apologies, method_b does not need to be nested in method_a.  My mind was multi-tasking while I wrote this.  I'll update the original post.  The other parts of my questions remain valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [`Kernel#caller`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-caller), which should give you the information you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ruby debugger then `where` command will spit out the call stack for you current code execution